# No data in injected model when using RouteServiceProvider.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

- Laravel Version: *7 or 8.**
- PHP Version: *7.4.**
- Database:
  *Postgresql* and *MariaDB*

#### Description:

I have defined a group in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
      'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        //  \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
      ],

      'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
      ],

      'auth.api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddBearerToken::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
      ],
    ];
```

`\App\Http\Middleware\AddBearerToken::class`:

```php
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Closure;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class AddBearerToken
  {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param $request
     * @param $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
        if ($request->hasCookie(env('ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME'))) {
          $token = $request->cookie(env('ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME'));
          $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
        }
      }

      return $next($request);
    }
  }
```

I define a new directory with routes in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
      $this->configureRateLimiting();

      $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
          ->middleware('api')
          ->namespace($this->namespace)
          ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        // Here
        Route::prefix('api/v1')
          ->middleware(['auth.api'])
          ->namespace($this->namespace)
          ->group(base_path('routes/Api/V1/Users/routes.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
          ->namespace($this->namespace)
          ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
      });
    }
```

I create a route:

```php
  Route::post('users/{user}/', function(User $user) {
    dd($user->toArray());
  });
```

In the output, I am getting an empty array.

But if I define this route, for example, in `api.php` like this:

```php
  Route::prefix('v1')
    ->group(function () {
      Route::middleware(['auth.api'])->group(function () {
        Route::post('users/{user}/', function(User $user) {
          dd($user->toArray());
        });
      });
    });
```

The model is there. If this is not a bug, then why does it work like that?

Comment: If you comment out the route in api.php, does the other route show when you run `php artisan r:l`?

Comment: @IGP I am using one route. In `api.php`, I gave an example when the result is expected. I expect a similar result when I use `RouteServiceProvider`. The `artisan r:l` command displays one route. Routes do not overlap.

Comment: Your `auth.api` middleware group does not include the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware. Add it in to the group and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `auth.api` middleware group does not include the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware. This is the middleware responsible for implicit route model binding.

Add this middleware into your `auth.api` middleware group and it should resolve your issue.